# glibc corruption; MALLOC_CHECK_ not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to track down the cause of a `glibc detected memory corruption` in our large legacy program (which spans multiple shared libraries).

(`valgrind` **does not** work with this software because of unknown op codes)

If the program is run 'as-is' it crashes out with the memory corruption error.  However, setting `MALLOC_CHECK_` to any value, the program works fine. Not helpful in tracking the root cause of the corruption.

Most posts related to tracking memory corruption use 10-line example code. We've got hundreds of thousands of lines of code, impossible to analyze each one.

What tools/techniques can I use to track down this bug?

The error happens when the program attempts `opendir` on a character constant string. But of course, that's likely not where the problem was introduced...

[image]

Comment: You clearly understand that "that's likely not where the problem was introduced". You said that yourself. From that, we can logically conclude that the stack trace in your question is equally meaningless. The cold hard truth is that the bug can be anywhere in your legacy code, and, unfortunately, there no magic button anywhere that you can push, and have the bug in your code present itself. Basically, the bug can be anywhere in the code that was executed up to the point that the program crashed. That's it.

Comment: Yup... sadly I know.  But I thought MALLOC_CHECK was supposed to help. Any other tracing tools out there?

Comment: If the crash is reproductible, then comment out a lot of code and see if it still crash...and add/remove code until you isolate the problem. Alternatively, if you have source control, try old versions until you have one version that does not crash. You might also be able to use data breakpoint or verify at some checkpoints if the memory is still right. If code is portable, you might try another compiler or tool.

Comment: What about recompile with `-fsanitize=address`?

Comment: Divide and conquer by commenting out will be difficult – its a huge program spread across 47 shared libraries.  But AddressSanitizer looks like it is worth a try.  Didn't know about that one. Thanks!