# Upgrade G++ to which minimum version for Centos 6 compatibility

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos6, devtoolset

Our large legacy app compiles with g++ 4.4.7 within 32-bit Centos-6.

However, I'd like to use Address Sanitizer to trouble shoot a problem with [glibc corruption; MALLOC_CHECK_ not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384664/glibc-corruption-malloc-check-not-working) but g++ 4.4.7 doesn't support Address Sanitizer.

I installed devtoolset-2 to get g++ `v4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)` but now the program doesn't compile because [exception_ptr.h Does not support exception propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400971/upgrading-to-g-4-8-exception-ptr-h-does-not-support-exception-propagation)

So thinking maybe a newer version of g++ will work.  I can't find any repo to install `devtoolset-3` on 32-bit Centos.  (Is there one?)

Otherwise, if I recompile g++ from source, which version to choose?  The [GCC Home Page](https://gcc.gnu.org/) lists all the way to v8.

Would compiling v8 break the other apps on the box (because of ABI incompatibiilty? - which I don't understand fully)?  Or best to pick the highest v4.x version?

Comment: The first thing I would do is, build the project with `-Wall -Wextra` and then fix the issues. The second is, stand up a CentOS 7 VM and use GCC 5.x which has Asan. The third thing I would do  is, build Valgrind from sources on Cent OS 6 (very easy). Then, build your large program and its dependent libraries with `-O1` (for why, [see here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)), and then see what happens. If those three failed to duplicate the issue, I would consider building a different version of GCC.

Comment: Try upgrading devtools to higher version as suggested in my answer in your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400971/upgrading-to-g-4-8-exception-ptr-h-does-not-support-exception-propagation/45479950#45479950

Comment: The project already compiles clean with `-Wall and -Wextra`.  I'll try the CentOS 7 VM idea.  Pe3k: Upgrading devtools didn't work. The instructions only apply to 64-bit and seems no 32-bit repo available (?)